# Accessing variables from class that implements an interface

Tags: variables, object, interface, polymorphism

Is it at all possible to access the variables/methods from ClassB in the following situation?

Where ClassB implements InterfaceA

```
InterfaceA object = new ClassB();

object.variable_from_classB
```

How can I get access to the methods and varables from class B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it's not possible. With languages like Java, which use static types, you will receive a compile error. Casting the `object` back to the `ClassB`, e.g.

```
((ClassB) object).variable_from_classB
```

would work in your case. If you use a language without static type information, the compiler has usually no chance in determining whether the variable can be accessed or is even present in the object. This will be decided at run-time.

In a statically-typed language which allows casting, the runtime environment will usually check casts and throw errors if they fail. So if `object` is not of type `ClassB`, the compiler won't report an error on the line above. However, the cast will fail at runtime because the concrete type of the object can't be cast to `ClassB`.

While the above cast alone would be valid, it is bad practice. At least, you should check whether the cast will succeed or not beforehand, e.g. use `instanceof` or whatever operator your language provides. It would be even better to you use variables/parameters of type `ClassB` instead of `InterfaceA`, if you need access to fields/methods of `ClassB`.

**References:**

- [Static vs. dynamic typing](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/10/03/static-vs-dynamic-typing-of-programming-languages/)

Comment: hi @nif thank you for your answer. When you say "use variables/parameters of type ClassB instead of InterfaceA, if you need access to fields/methods of ClassB" do you mean I should just create another instance like ClassB varObj = new ClassB(); and then access my variables through varObj?

Comment: I mean, if you need things from `ClassB` don't declare your variable to be of `InterfaceA` in the first place. Just because `ClassB` implements `InterfaceA` doesn't mean you must use it.